# Creating python lists of mapped values from keys in a list of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a python dict as below

```
mymap={'java':40,'haskell':60,'ruby':50,'python':70,'scala':30,'lisp':80,'scheme':75}
```

I have the keys put in sublists

```
mapkeys = [['haskell','java'],['lisp','python'],['scala','scheme'],['ruby']]
```

Now,I need to create a list of lists of values of these keys as below

```
[[60,40],[80,70],[30,75],[50] ]
```

I tried using list comprehension ,but failed to yield any results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> [[mymap[k] for k in l] for l in mapkeys]
[[60, 40], [80, 70], [30, 75], [50]]
```

For a non-nested list, remove the brackets and reverse the `for` statements:

```
>>> [mymap[k] for l in mapkeys for k in l]
[60, 40, 80, 70, 30, 75, 50]
```

Comment: For a non-nested list, iterating over `sum(mapkeys,[])` is also an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

In case that you find lambda expressions easier to read than list comprehension syntax:

```
map(lambda l: map(mymap.get,l), mapkeys)
```

(Personally, I'd say "terse to the point of unreadability", but I'll let you make up your mind.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
[[mymap[k] for k in sublist] for sublist in mapkeys]
```